# angular $locationChangeStart not getting called properly, what do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, pug

I'm working on a MEAN  app that is based upon Brian Ford's angular-express-blog app on GitHub.

The problem I'm having is that I need to be able to call my UserService service on $locationChangeStart in order to check if there is a user logged. Most of the examples I see have you setting `$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart'...` in the module declaration. This doesn't allow me to access my custom service so my solution was to put it in a controller and call it in my main layout file.

I've set it up like so but the app does nothing. It doesn't even call an error. Can any of you spot the problem with this code?

Here is my github [repo.](https://github.com/Rorschach120/angularexpressapp)

LayoutCtrl.js:

```
angular.module('myApp').
    controller('LayoutCtrl', function($scope, $http, UserService) {
        $scope.$on( "$locationChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {
            if ( UserService.getUser() === null ) {
        // no logged user, we should be going to #login
                if ( next.templateUrl == "partials/login.html" ) {
          // already going to #login, no redirect needed
                } else {
          // not going to #login, we should redirect now
                $location.path( "/login" );
                }
            }         
        });
    });
```

Layout.jade:

```
doctype html
html(ng-app="myApp", ng-controller='LayoutCtrl')
  head
    meta(charset='utf8')
    base(href='/')
    title Angular Express Seed App
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/app.css')
  body
    block body
```

And UserService.js:

```
angular.module('myApp').
    service('UserService', function(){
        var $scope = this;
        var user = null;
        $scope.user = {};

        $scope.setUser = function(data){
                user = data;
        };
        $scope.getUser = function(){
                $scope.user = user;
        };

        return $scope;
  });
```

Comment: can you please post your entire application. Including all html/js neccecary

Comment: I've posted the relevant code as there is a lot of code. Is there anything in specific you can think of that I could copy/paste from the github repo (which is included in the post)?

Comment: Ah,  it's 1.0.3 which is totally outdated... I assumed that the guy who made the seed app kept it updated since he works for google and all. Thank you! However I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Have you tried to put the code in the app.run block ?

Comment: Can I used that outside of the app module declaration file? Because I was having a problem due to my custom service.

Comment: you can inject services into run blocks...

Comment: yes but anything in the app module declaration runs before the service is actually created.

Comment: you are wrong, a service is never instantiated before the first time it has to be injected. if your run block declares a service as a dependency then first this service will be instantiated and just then would be injected to the run block, that's what dependency injection is all about don't it?!.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't understand how your service is supposed to work, your getUser function returns nothing (undefined).

Use this instead:

```
angular.module('myApp').
    service('UserService', function(){
        var user;

        this.setUser = function(data){
          user = data;
        };
        this.getUser = function(){
          return user;
        };
  });
```

so your problem is that undefiend !== null

and you are checking for this:

```
 if ( UserService.getUser() === null )
```

if you want to check if it's undefined (or other falsy values) use this:

```
 if ( ! UserService.getUser() )
```

also you should inject $location:

```
 controller('LayoutCtrl', function($scope, UserService, $location) {
```

#### Debugging

- use console.log to check the flow of your application
- `console.log(UserService.getUser()) # undefined`

#### alternative solution with a run block :

```
angular.module('myApp').
    run(function($rootScope, UserService, $location) {
        $rootScope.$on( "$locationChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {

        });
    });
```

Comment: I ended up putting it in my layout controller and it is working fine now. Back to learning more angular. Thank you again for the help!